# Django form – sending uploaded files as attachments over email

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Basically, the title says it all.

This is the code I'm using:

```
documents = self.request.FILES.getlist('my_documents')

mail = EmailMessage(
    'Subject Line',
    'Message Body!',
    'from_email',
    ['to_email']
)
for d in documents:
    mail.attach(d.name, d.file.read(), d.content_type)
mail.send()
```

Sending the email works fine, and I do get the attachments.

However, there seems to be a problem with the content of those attachments.

Trying to open the files does not work.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it has something to do with the encoding of the second argument of the mail.attach function, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

The code should say:

```
for d in documents:
    mail.attach(d.name, d.read(), d.content_type)
```

instead of:

```
for d in documents:
    mail.attach(d.name, d.file.read(), d.content_type)
```